# "to put someone up for the night"

Tags: writing, idiomatic-language

Imagine you want to invite your friend to your home because you are having a birthday party. Since your friend live far away, you think you should offer him to stay with you for the night.

How would you say that in different ways in an invitation mail? I especially look for something idiomatic  but without too formal or informal..

For example :

> We would be more than happy to put you up for the night?

How about ?

> We would be more than happy to have you for the night.
>
> After the party, you can stay with us overnight.
>
> After the party, you can sleep at our home overnight.

Comment: "Feel free to stay the night if that's convenient"

Comment: Those all sound pretty good to me, although I'd probably say _at our **house**_ instead of _at our **home**_ (although _**in** our home_ would be fine, albeit a bit on the informal side).

Comment: American slang for sleeping over is "After the party, you can crash at our place".

Comment: Depending on how much you know about the other person/people, you may need to be a little careful - "We would be more than happy to have you for the night." is perilously close to having sexual connotations, that you probably didn't intend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are happy to put you up for the night

is fine, as well as:

> You can stay here if you want.
>
> You can spend the night here if you want.
>
> Why don't you sleep here tonight? ([And in the morning I'm making waffles!](https://youtu.be/1Gz8d4Kay84?t=74))

As John Felz mentions, "crash" is AmE slang for this:

> You can crash here tonight.

Other related idioms for *sleep* that can be used: "sack out", "bed down", "get some shut-eye".